# Exists() and getSymbols() can't find symbol listed in yahoo

Tags: r, quantmod

For some reason, even though PRIO3F.SA is listed on [yahoo](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PRIO3F.SA/)(and also other symbols aside from this one specifically), when I do exists() it simply doesn't find anything.
This is for a school project and quite a few symbols can't be found with this method. Is quantmod (or maybe yahoo finance) not my best place to go to?

I've tried multiple different symbol variations and still failing.

```r
> exists("PRIO3F.SA")
[1] FALSE
> exists("PRIO3.SA")
[1] FALSE
> exists("PRIO3F")
[1] FALSE
> exists("PRIO3")
[1] FALSE
```

If by any chance I try to use getSymbols() instead, this is what greets me:

```
> getSymbols("PRIO3F.SA", src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE)
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "PRIO3F.SA", env = <environment>,  : 
  Unable to import “PRIO3F.SA”.
attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

Comment: `exists` checks to see if there is an object in the local R environment (or in its search path) with that name, why are you looking for those variables _before_ you try to `getSymbols(..)` them? For instance, `exists("mtcars")` returns `TRUE` because there is an object in your search path with that name (a data.frame).

Comment: `getSymbols(..., auto.assign=FALSE)` should be returning something _that you then store_ into an object. Calling it without assigning its output seems odd, since you'll fetch it, render what the output looks like on the console, and then discard it, not to be used for anything else. Is there a reason you're (mis)using it in that way?

Comment: I ran that line of getSymbols solely to check it's input! That's not how my project is looking like as of now. About exists, so ideally the correct way to check if the given symbol is valid should be running getSymbols instead of exists? Orrr? Ideally I'd need a function where I can check if the given symbol is valid (tons from my professor's csv is not and need to be tweaked here and there)

Comment: First, I'm not a fan of `getSymbols`'s default method of storing the return value in the current environment as the symbol's name, I prefer a more functional method, and your use of `auto.assign=FALSE` is aligned with that preference. Second, the use of `exists(..)` must have been somebody's safeguard to you to make sure that consecutive calls to `getSymbols` (same symbol, perhaps different arguments) would overwrite each other, where `exists("PRIO3F.SA")` only tells you that an object of that name exists and it _might_ be from a prior call to `getSymbols("PRIO3F.SA",...)`.

Comment: But `exists` is base R, nothing to do with `quantmod`, and its uses are much more general than this. I don't know if `quantmod` documentation suggests it (it's not a bad recommendation, tbh, but not enough for me to be a fan of automatic assignment). The fact that `exists(..)` returns `FALSE` means nothing in quantmod-land. If the call is failing, then it's due to something else I suspect.

Comment: JoshuaUlrich has pointed out a new point, and since Joshua is the package author, I would take it as more authoritative than my (since-debunked) theory of URL-change or a bug. Please accept the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo does not provide historical daily data for every ticker symbol. That's the problem in this case.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since I can call `getSymbols("MSFT",src="yahoo",auto.assign = FALSE)` successfully while `getSymbols("PRIO3F.SA",src="yahoo",auto.assign = FALSE)` *fails* (for me as well), that suggests the API may have changed. I `debug`ged the call to `getSymbols.yahoo` (internal) and it appears that the URL being generated automatically

```
yahoo.URL
# [1] "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/PRIO3F.SA?period1=1167609600&period2=1688688000&interval=1d"
```

and the URL shown within Yahoo!'s own finance page are different. While debugging, if I replace it with (while deep within debugging)

```
yahoo.URL <- "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/PRIO3F.SA?region=US&lang=en-US&includePrePost=false&interval=2m&useYfid=true&range=1d&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance"

## for comparison ...
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/PRIO3F.SA?period1=1167609600&period2=1688688000&interval=1d
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/PRIO3F.SA?region=US&lang=en-US&includePrePost=false&interval=2m&useYfid=true&range=1d&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance
```

it works. Note that the url generated by `getSymbols.yahoo` includes the period whereas the url I sniffed in the browser does not. I'm sure this will be the source of some more investigation.

I suggest you submit a bug-report to the authors, since it appears Yahoo! may have updated their API and/or tightened their expectations. (Perhaps it's CORS or the source country of my request or any number of things.)

Comment: This isn't a bug. Yahoo doesn't provide daily data for every ticker. The URL you found is intraday data (every 2 minutes for 1 day). The URL can be simplified to `https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/PRIO3F.SA?interval=1m&range=1d`.